# need a function that divides the total number of rows by the number of rows with specific text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can’t write a condition that will allow me to count the total number of lines, divide them by the number of lines that contain the word `Tetris` and display the result of the division

Trying

```sql
Select count(*) 
From table_name
Where main/(select main from table_name where main="Tetris")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The data that you get from the database is only what you put in the `SELECT` clause. The `WHERE` clause is exclusively here to filter according to a predicate.

Your query would work by just moving the troublesome part inside the `SELECT` clause. Note that to have a ratio, you need to convert `COUNT(*)` to a floating-point number with a cast operation.
Lastly, string values in `sql` are single-quoted. Double-quotes are for identifiers.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)::DECIMAL / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE main='Tetris')
FROM table_name
```

A slightly better version of the above makes use of `FILTER` for aggregation functions:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)::DECIMAL / COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE main='Tetris')
FROM table_name
```

Or here is a version with `CASE`, that makes use of the fact that `NULL` values do not participate to the counts.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)::DECIMAL / COUNT(CASE WHEN main='Tetris' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sum one for every row divided by the sum of every Tetris row:

```
SELECT  SUM(1.0) / SUM(CASE WHEN main='Tetris' THEN 1 END)
FROM    table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to compute is the reciprocal of the occurrence rate of 'tetris'. Other than the various possible solutions offered by Atmo, here is an alternative using the aggregate function AVG.

```
SELECT 1.0 / AVG(CASE WHEN main = 'tetris' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)
FROM table_name;
```